# Removing element from another Arraylist

Tags: java

```
ArrayList<Room> roomlist = new ArrayList<Roomlist>();
ArrayList<Subscriber> subscriberlist = new ArrayList<subscriber>();
ArrayList<Course> courserslist = new ArrayList<coursers>();
ArrayList<PC> pclist = new ArrayList<PC>();
ArrayList<Lecturer>  lecturertlist= new ArrayList <Lecturer>() ;
```

How can i check if element of Subscriber in the list of Cource exist , an remove him from

courselist (Not delete him )

Many Thanks

Comment: We need more information about `Subscriber` and `Course`. Moreover, please respect the Java convention, specially the class name must begin by an uppercase character :)

Comment: adding to Nizil comment, You can use arraylist indexof and arraylist remove methods

Answer (score 0):

If your `Subscriber` as follows and assume your `Course` is some what similar to my class in bellow . you can try some thing like following

```
public class Subscriber {
private List<Course> courses=new ArrayList<>();

public List<Course> getCourses() {
    return courses;
}

public void setCourses(List<Course> courses) {
    this.courses = courses;
}
}
```

.

```
public class Course {
private int courseId;
private String courseName;

public int getCourseId() {
    return courseId;
}

public void setCourseId(int courseId) {
    this.courseId = courseId;
}

public String getCourseName() {
    return courseName;
}

public void setCourseName(String courseName) {
    this.courseName = courseName;
}
}
```

now lets remove an element.

```
    List<Subscriber> subscribers=new ArrayList<>();
    List<Course> courses=new ArrayList<>();        
    Subscriber subscriber=new Subscriber();
    Course course=new Course();
    course.setCourseId(1);
    course.setCourseName("one");
    courses.add(course);
    subscriber.setCourses(courses);
    subscribers.add(subscriber);
    for (Subscriber i:subscribers){
         i.getCourses().remove(0);  // remove 0 index element 
    }
```

Comment: @D-LauryLaury you are welcome. If this was an answer to your question accept this as answer